# Visual Studio - Change default "View Code" editor while keeping default editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, editor, default

I have a project in Visual Studio 2017 (Professional) in which I'm editing an SSRS `.rdlc` file.

I have it such that the default editor for the file is, as I'd want it to be, the `Report Designer`.

However, I'm often editing the source XML for that file. So, I'm often right-clicking the file and selecting `View Code`. When I do that, it opens the file up in a standard Text editor rather than the XML editor.

What I'd like to have happen is:

1. Have `Report Designer` be the standard default editor.
2. Have `XML Editor` be the default editor for when I want to view code.

Is there any way to set that up to be the case (just change the default `View Code` editor)?

Answer (score -2):

Right click on your report and open with it will show you something like this [image]

and you can choose what you want

Comment: Unfortunately, like I stated in my question / title, that's not what I'm looking for - I know how to change the default editor, but I want to keep the default editor the Report Designer. I just want to change the default editor for when I select `view code`